# Saving Excel VBA Userforms as PDFs

Tags: excel, vba, forms, pdf, userform

I have created a userform in Excel which works Pretty well. Unfortunately, I´m having Troubles with saving the forms. The Idea is, that several collegues can use this form, so having a Standard saving Folder or drive is not working because not all collegues have Access to all drives. I would like to have a window appearing, which asks the user where to save the document as a pdf. I know there is the command "saveCopyAs" but I cant get it running with PDF as Format.

Comment: What specifically do you want saving as pdf? The picture of the form, its text code? Do you know that the form can be exported (as a .frm file) and then imported in another workbook? Should I show you how can you do that in VBA? But, if you really need it as pdf, please clarify the first questions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The Userform inserts Information into a sheet. And I´m trying to save that specific sheet as pdf.

Comment: So your question is not about userform but simply about saving an Excel sheet as PDF? Can you please reword your question. You are probably looking for `Workbook.ExportAsFixedFormat` (which took me approx. 30s to figure out using the search engine of my choice)

Comment: Hey,
yes the wording of my Question is bit unfortunate. Let me try again: I have a userform, that inserts Information into an Excel sheet. Within that userform, I want a button which inserts the Information into the sheet (which already works) but I also want that button to automatically save that specific sheet as pdf (and perferrably lets the user Chose the place where it sould be saved) without the user clicking around in the Excel sheet itself. So basically everything should happen within that userform. Thank you

Comment: Then, try the code I posted. It export the active sheet as pdf...

Comment: Consider making an [edit] to clarify your post instead of putting all the important information in comments

Comment: You are Right. Sorry I´m new to this website

Answer (score 1):

Try the next simple code, please. Run your code to export the form in the way you do, activate the sheet where this action happens and run the next code, or insert these code lines inside the procedure making the export:

```
Sub exportShAsPDF()
   Dim strPath As String
     
   strPath = folderPicker 'the ending "\" included...
   ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, fileName:= _
                                             strPath & "Form.pdf"
End Sub
```

Use the next function to choose the folder where to save the pdf file:

```
Function folderPicker() As String
  Dim tempFileDialog As FileDialog, initialFolder As String, strN As String
    
    initialFolder = "C:\"
    
    Set tempFileDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    
    With tempFileDialog
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .InitialFileName = initialFolder
        If Not .Show = -1 Then Exit Function
    End With
    strN = tempFileDialog.SelectedItems(1)
    folderPicker = left(strN, InStrRev(strN, "\"))
End Function
```

Comment: @MarkAKE: Did you find some  time to check the above code? If tested, didn't it solve your problem?